# Rust By Exampleに書いてある「名前付きタプル」とは何ですか？

Tags: rust

Rust初心者です。Rust By Exampleの[構造体の章](https://doc.rust-jp.rs/rust-by-example-ja/custom_types/structs.html) に、

> structというキーワードを用いて作成できる構造体には3種類あります。
>
> - タプル。（ほとんどの場合は名前付きタプル）
> - クラシックなC言語スタイルの構造体。
> - ユニット。これはフィールドを持たず、ジェネリック型を扱う際に有効です。

と書いてあり、このあとにサンプルコードも載っていたのですが、「名前付きタプル」とはどれなのかがわかりませんでした。
わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

Comment: 参考: [Docs.rs: Crate named_tuple](https://docs.rs/named_tuple/0.1.3/named_tuple/)

Comment: (答 付いてるけど補足？)
普通の tupleは `pair.0`, `pair.1` とか indexing (indexでアクセス)する。named_tuple だと名前でアクセスできる。Example内だと, `peter.name()` とか

Comment: @oriri 私も最初は`pair.0`, `pair.1`の`0`, `1`の部分に名前が付くという意味かと思ったのですが、そうではなく、`(i32, i32)`が名前の無いタプリ型、`Pair(i32, i32)`が名前付きのタプル型のようです。Example内の`Peter`は名前付きタプルではなく、２番目の「クラシックなC言語スタイルの構造体」のようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[英語版](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/custom_types/structs.html)は以下のようになっています:

> There are three types of structures ("structs") that can be created using the struct keyword:
>
> - Tuple structs, which are, basically, named tuples.
> - The classic C structs
> - Unit structs, which are field-less, are useful for generics.

該当部分"*Tuple structs, which are, basically, named tuples.*"は「タプル構造体（おおむね名前のついたタプルのようなもの）」くらいの意味です。
つまり、「タプル構造体は、普通のタプルに名前がついたようなもの」ということです。

Answer (score 3):

名前付きでない、普通のタプルと比較すると分かりやすいかなと思います。

サンプルコード中では、以下が名前付きのタプルです。`Pair` という名前のついたタプル型と見なせる構造体になっています。

```
struct Pair(i32, f32);
```

名前付きでない普通のタプルは、カッコの中で値を並べたものです。たとえば以下のコードにおける `(i32, f32)` は名前のない単なるタプル型ですし、`(42, 3.14)` というのはタプル型の値です。

```
let t: (i32, f32) = (42, 3.14);
```

Rust by Example としては以下のページを参照ください: https://doc.rust-jp.rs/rust-by-example-ja/primitives/tuples.html

これに加えて、クラシックな構造体を使うことでフィールドにも名前がついたタプルのように扱うこともできます。こちらのことを名前付きタプル (tuple with named fields) と呼ぶこともあります。

Answer (score 0):

コメント見ると, 微妙な齟齬ありそうなので, 一応回答として記します
([もとの英語のページ](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/custom_types/structs.html)の, 内容のみを読み取り, 表現を少し無視した形が一番よさそうな？)

---

記されてる内容からすると …
構造体(structures) を作成(can be created) する時, `struct` キーワードに 構造体名(struct’s name) が続き, 3つの段階で指定できる

- (normal(？) structs): 各データに名前(項目名) が付いたもの
- tuple structs: 名前付きフィールド(名前付き項目)でないもの ([without Named Fields](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#using-tuple-structs-without-named-fields-to-create-different-types))
- unit-like structs: フィールド(項目) のないもの

要は, すべて指定するか, 項目名省略するか, 項目そのもの省略するか … の違い

"tuple structs" と呼ばれるている(called tuple structs) ものも, 普通の Tupleに似てる, 程度で, 「Tupleと言えばこれ」という訳ではないし
"The classic C structs" という表現は, 「よく見かける C言語のそれに似てるね」程度の理解でよいかも
(何が classic なのか不明)

ということで
named_tuple とは記されていない模様, 「名前付きタプル」は言葉尻つかまえたようなもの
正しくは
「つまり(要するに), 名前(構造体名)の付いた Tuple(のような)」(basically, named tuples) であり

named_tuple として, 一番近そうなのは [通常の structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#defining-and-instantiating-structs)

Comment: 翻訳ドキュメント: [構造体を定義し、インスタンス化する](https://doc.rust-jp.rs/book-ja/ch05-01-defining-structs.html#構造体を定義しインスタンス化する)